# How to create a sum formula if the number of rows vary?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am curious how to create a sum formula in excel if the number of rows varies. For example, if I have a worksheet with a header in A1. This worksheet also has 100 values under it. If I want to sum all of the rows, I would use =sum(A2:A100). However, lets say then a few more numbers are added, I rather would not re-enter the formula to account for the added values. I tried using =sum(A2:A) but that does not return a value for me.

*from comments (sic)*

So the header is actually in A3. I tried =`sum(A:A)-A1-A1-A3` but that did not work

Comment: Does the header contain a number? If not use =sum(a:a), if so use =sum(a:a)-a1

Comment: You could also use =sum(a2:index(a:a, match(1e99, a:a)) but that is not necessary.

Comment: So the header is actually in A3. I tried =sum(A:A)-A1-A1-A3 but that did not work

Comment: Can you convert the column to a table?

Comment: With a minimum of offence @GCC, just state what you are trying to do the first time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your header in A3 and the first summable number in A4,

```
=sum(a4:index(a:a, max(4, match(1e99, a:a)))
```